# DASK - Read Huge CSV and write to 255 differenct CSV files

Tags: python, csv, dask

I am using [DASK](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) to read CSV file which sizes around 2GB.
I want to write each row of it to separate 255 number CSV files based on some hash function as below.

#### My naive solution:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = dd.read_csv('train.csv', header=None, dtype='str')
    df = df.fillna()
    for _, line in df.iterrows():
        number = hash(line[2]) % 256
        with open("{}.csv".format(number), 'a+') as f:
            f.write(', '.join(line))
```

This way takes around 15 minutes. Is there any way we can do it faster.

Comment: Since you're not doing anything fancy with your CSV, why not just use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module? Also, you should cache your file handlers so you don't keep opening and closing the files on each row of your CSV - it's ok in your case to keep 256 open file handles and close them in the end.

Comment: Thanks @zwer so should I open all files before and try to loop over data?

Comment: You can open them on demand... Make a dictionary to hold your map, say `file_map`, then just do something like `f = file_map.get(number)` and `if f is None: f = file_map[number] = open('{}.csv'.format(number), 'a+')` instead of your `with ...` line. Then just go through all of them and close the handles once you've iterated over the full length of your CSV.

Comment: Ok right now trying with csv reader and writing to only one file but it is still taking more time.

Comment: According to you what is the ideal time for this kind of task?

Answer (score 2):

Since your procedure is dominated by IO, it is very unlikely that Dask would do anything but add overhead in this case, *unless* your hash function is really really slow. I assume that is not the case.

@zwer 's solution would look something like

```
files = [open("{}.csv".format(number), 'a+') for number in range(255)]
for _, line in df.iterrows():
    number = hash(line[2]) % 256
    files[number].write(', '.join(line))
[f.close() for f in files]
```

However, your data appears to fit in memory, so you may find much better performance

```
for (number, group) in df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 2].map(hash)):
    group.to_csv("{}.csv".format(number))
```

because you write to each file continuously rather than jumping between them. Depending on your IO device and buffering, the difference can be none or huge.

Comment: Thanks mdurant I would definitely try this.